# display input fields in customized way

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dynamic form. My input fields belong to different groups. I want to figure out a way to display them group-wise.

My state through which form input fields are generated is:

```
random:
{
name: "emp1", group: "employee",
name: "emp2", group: "employee",
name: "emp3", group: "employee",
name: "man1", group: "manager",
name: "man2", group: "manager"

}
```

My dynamic form is as follows:

```
const Form = (props) => {
  return (

    <div>
      {props.items.map(item => (
          name={item.key_name}
          value={item.key_value}
          onChange={e => props.handleChange(e)}
        />
      )
      )}

      <button onClick={() => props.handleSubmit()} >
       Submit
      </button>

    </div>

  )
}
export default Form
```

right now my fields are generated side by side in a horizontal line
But I want to display them group wise; so something like this:

```
Employee: (3 input fields)
Manager: (2 input fields)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to split your items by their group, then render them. I would make the group a component so it handles rendering the label and also the inputs

```
const Form = props => {
  const itemsByGroup = {};
  props.items.forEach(item => {
    if (!itemsByGroup[item.group]) {
      itemsByGroup[item.group] = [];
    }
    itemsByGroup[item.group].push(item);
  });
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(itemsByGroup).map(groupName => (
        <FormGroup
          label={groupName}
          fields={itemsByGroup[groupName]}
          handleChange={props.handleChange}
          key={groupName}
        />
      ))}

      <button onClick={() => props.handleSubmit()}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const FormGroup = ({ label, fields, handleChange }) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}:</label>
    {fields.map(field => (
      <input
        name={field.key_name}
        value={field.key_value}
        onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

### [See a live example here to play with](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-czumn)

## Edit

if you have to put it in one component you can just do this

```
const Form = props => {
  const itemsByGroup = {};
  props.items.forEach(item => {
    if (!itemsByGroup[item.group]) {
      itemsByGroup[item.group] = [];
    }
    itemsByGroup[item.group].push(item);
  });
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(itemsByGroup).map(groupName => (
        <div>
          <label>{label}:</label>
          {fields.map(field => (
            <input
              name={field.key_name}
              value={field.key_value}
              onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}

      <button onClick={() => props.handleSubmit()}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Oh great! Works perfect! Thanks

Comment: @user8306074 yep! i used a constant mapper so that its dynamic for any number of groups you pass through. You can apply styles to the label element like `text-transform: capitalize;` for instance to capitalize the title of the group. :)

Comment: Cool! I like the way you incorporated the dynamic part.! Thanks

Comment: hi, https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-morse-wxesc this is my code. Im finding it very difficult to incorporate your changes into this. Can you help me out ?

Comment: I dont want to create a separate component; is there any way to display the display the items group-wise in the same component. Because, if I do that then I'll have to change the entire logic of mapping values and names and that is quite a tedious process.

Comment: Do you just want it to be in one component?

Comment: @user8306074 updated ur sandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-lichterman-gsww7